# How can I add CSS transitions to my jQuery Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've set up a tab system with the following jQuery code. Now I want to make the content change smoothly I've tried adding a transition: all 0.3s ease; to the div but not had any luck with this, where am I going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".icon").click(function(e){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var tabNum = $(this).index();
            var nthChild = tabNum+1;
            $(".icon.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".pos__content-item.active").removeClass("active");
            $(".pos__content-item:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
      .pos__content-item {
        display: none;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }
      .pos__content-item.active {
        height: 20em;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 5em 0em;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
        @media (max-width: 1000px) {
          height: 30em;
        }
```

Comment: Please post the css you're using.

Comment: Added the css code

Comment: What properties are you trying to have transition? Not all properties are transition-able. There's nothing defined in `.pos__content-item` that will transition when the `.active` class gets adds. `display` doesn't transition, but `opacity` will.

Comment: This should be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: basically, I'm replacing the content of the div with a different set of text and a different image using the active class to hide and display the new and old content. If I can't use transition with display what would be my best method to animate the content change?

Comment: @SamDucker your HTML code?